# Laravel testing Failed asserting that two strings are equal

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I am very new to testing, but have now found it essential to automate my testing.

I have a test that is working fine up until it gets to the link '/cart' it gets to the link '/cart' no problem, but any other link I try to click afterwards always ends up back at the cart.

here is my error after trying to navigate away from the cart.

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://ngwenya-mtb.dev/events'
+'http://ngwenya-mtb.dev/cart'
```

And here is my test script

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {




//use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
//use DatabaseTransactions; 
//use withoutMiddleware;
//use DatabaseMigrations;
/**
 * 
 * A basic functional test example.
 * Please choose a unique email address for your new participant
 * @return void
 */
public function testNewUserRegistration() {

    $this->visit('http://ngwenya-mtb.dev/')
        // View Event
        ->click('View event details')
        ->seePageIs('/event?id=30')

        ->click('#enter-race47')
        ->press('Enter yourself to this race')

        ->seePageIs('/events/courses/register/addtocart')
        //->withSession(['This email is already registered' => 'alert-danger'])

        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //  Fill the register for for new user
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        ->type('Bingo', 'first_name')
        ->type('11111111', 'password')
        ->type('11111111', 'password_confirmation')
        ->type(''.substr(md5(time()), 0, 12).'@tesing.com', 'email')
        //->check('terms')
        ->select('Male', 'gender')
        ->select('1985', 'year')
        ->select('07', 'month')
        ->select('21', 'day')
        ->select('Small', 'shirt_size')
        ->select('Swaziland ID', 'id_type')
        ->type('badassnumber', 'id_number')
        ->select('Swazi', 'nationality')
        //Contact details Physical
        ->type('Dawlish', 'town_physical')
        ->select('Swaziland', 'country_physical')
        ->type('864741', 'phone_cell')
        //Emergency contact details 1
        ->type('Simon', 'emergency_contact_1')
        ->type('Brother', 'emergency_relationship_1')
        ->type('864741', 'emergency_phone_1');


        $this->press('Register');
        $this->seePageIs('/cart');


        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        //  Add a new user
        /////////////////////////////////////////////

        $this->visit('http://ngwenya-mtb.dev/');
        $this->click('#events-link')

        ->seePageIs('/events');
        dd($this->response->getContent());exit;
        $this->click('#event-30');
        $this->seePageIs('/event?id=30');

        $this->click('#enter-race48');
        $this->press('Enter someone else to this race');
        $this->seePageIs('/events/courses/register/addtocart');             
    }

}
```

Everything is working fine up until this comment

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Add a new user
/////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Here is my Registration controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Vinkla\Hashids\HashidsManager;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Sentinel\FormRequests\RegisterRequest;
use Sentinel\FormRequests\EmailRequest;
use Sentinel\FormRequests\ResetPasswordRequest;
use Sentinel\Repositories\Group\SentinelGroupRepositoryInterface;
use Sentinel\Repositories\User\SentinelUserRepositoryInterface;
use Sentinel\Traits\SentinelRedirectionTrait;
use Sentinel\Traits\SentinelViewfinderTrait;
use Sentry;
use View;
use Request;
use Event;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Config;
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Traits
     */
    use SentinelRedirectionTrait;
    use SentinelViewfinderTrait;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        SentinelUserRepositoryInterface $userRepository,
        SentinelGroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        HashidsManager $hashids
    ) {
        $this->userRepository       = $userRepository;
        $this->groupRepository      = $groupRepository;
        $this->hashids              = $hashids;
    }

    /**
     * Show the registration form, if registration is allowed
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registration()
    {
        // Is this user already signed in? If so redirect to the post login route
        if (Sentry::check()) {
            return $this->redirectTo('session_store');
        }

        //If registration is currently disabled, show a message and redirect home.
        if (! config('sentinel.registration', false)) {
            return $this->redirectTo(['route' => 'home'], ['error' => trans('Sentinel::users.inactive_reg')]);
        }

        // All clear - show the registration form.
        return $this->viewFinder(config('sentinel.view.user_register', 'Sentinel::users.register'));
    }

    /**
     * Process a registration request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
    {

        // Gather input
        $data = $request->all();

        // collect cart items
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $course_id = Input::get('course_id');
        $event_name = Input::get('event_name');
        $entry_fee = Input::get('entry_fee');

        // check user exists
        if (Users::where('email', '=', $email)->exists()) {
            // user found
            $request->session()->flash('alert-danger', 'Warning: This email is already registered.');
            Input::flash();
            return View::make('sentinel.users.register')
                    ->with('course_id',$course_id)
                    ->with('event_name',$event_name)
                    ->with('entry_fee',$entry_fee);
        }

        // Add user and course to cart
        if ($course_id) {
            $firstUserRowId = Cart::add($course_id, $event_name , 1, $entry_fee, [  
                    'first_name' => Input::get('first_name'),
                    'last_name' => Input::get('last_name'), 
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'no_email' => 0,
                    'master_user' => 1,
                    'gender' => Input::get('gender'),
                    'dob' => Input::get('dob'),
                    'shirt_size' => Input::get('shirt_size'),
                    'id_type' => Input::get('id_type'),
                    'id_number' => Input::get('id_number'),
                    'nationality' => Input::get('nationality'),
                    'phone_cell' => Input::get('phone_cell'),
                    'town_physical' => Input::get('town_physical'),
                    'country_physical' => Input::get('country_physical'),
                    'emergency_contact_1' => Input::get('emergency_contact_1'),
                    'emergency_relationship_1' => Input::get('emergency_relationship_1'),
                    'emergency_phone_1' => Input::get('emergency_phone_1'),
                ]);             
        }



        // get email from request
        $email = $request->only('email');
        foreach ($email as $userModel) {}

        // Edit date of birth from request
        $year = Input::get('year');
        $month = Input::get('month');
        $day = Input::get('day');       
        $dob = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
        $data['dob'] = $dob;

        // Attempt Registration
        $result = $this->userRepository->store($data);                        

        // Log user in
        FunctionsController::loginUser($userModel);

        // It worked!  Use config to determine where we should go.
        return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_complete', $result);
    }

    /**
     * Activate a new user
     *
     * @param  int    $id
     * @param  string $code
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function activate($hash, $code)
    {
        // Decode the hashid
        $id = $this->hashids->decode($hash)[0];

        // Attempt the activation
        $result = $this->userRepository->activate($id, $code);

        // It worked!  Use config to determine where we should go.
        return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_activated', $result);
    }

    /**
     * Show the 'Resend Activation' form
     *
     * @return View
     */
    public function resendActivationForm()
    {
        return $this->viewFinder('Sentinel::users.resend');
    }

    /**
     * Process resend activation request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function resendActivation(EmailRequest $request)
    {
        // Resend the activation email
        $result = $this->userRepository->resend(['email' => e($request->get('email'))]);

        // It worked!  Use config to determine where we should go.
        return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_resend', $result);
    }

    /**
     * Display the "Forgot Password" form
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function forgotPasswordForm()
    {
        return $this->viewFinder('Sentinel::users.forgot');
    }


    /**
     * Process Forgot Password request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function sendResetPasswordEmail(EmailRequest $request)
    {
        // Send Password Reset Email
        $result = $this->userRepository->triggerPasswordReset(e($request->get('email')));

        // It worked!  Use config to determine where we should go.
        return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_reset_triggered', $result);
    }

    /**
     * A user is attempting to reset their password
     *
     * @param $id
     * @param $code
     *
     * @return Redirect|View
     */
    public function passwordResetForm($hash, $code)
    {
        // Decode the hashid
        $id = $this->hashids->decode($hash)[0];

        // Validate Reset Code
        $result = $this->userRepository->validateResetCode($id, $code);

        if (! $result->isSuccessful()) {
            return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_reset_invalid', $result);
        }

        return $this->viewFinder('Sentinel::users.reset', [
            'hash' => $hash,
            'code' => $code
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Process a password reset form submission
     *
     * @param $hash
     * @param $code
     * @return Response
     */
    public function resetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest $request, $hash, $code)
    {
        // Decode the hashid
        $id = $this->hashids->decode($hash)[0];

        // Gather input data
        $data = $request->only('password', 'password_confirmation');

        // Change the user's password
        $result = $this->userRepository->resetPassword($id, $code, e($data['password']));

        // It worked!  Use config to determine where we should go.
        return $this->redirectViaResponse('registration_reset_complete', $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your controller method that handles the Register form submit.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the controller. The function is `public function register(RegisterRequest $request)`

Comment: Can you show `$this->redirectViaResponse` method?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you click and a your link "Register" your redirection fail, so check if you have multiple "Register" links/buttons, and if they are pointing to the right URL

And for easiest debugging, you should make less assertions per Test, you will gain in visibility :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Register seems to work as the database gets updated with the user details and then it redirects to the cart. Is it an issue with the redirect to the cart?

Comment: When you manualy click on register after filling your form, is your form submit to the /cart page ? Or have you an intermediate page ?

Comment: No there is no intermediate page. It does the registration then routes to the cart.